# Any pattern for multi user type?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a system with differents kind of users:

SuperAdmin, FederationPresident, AssociationPresident, ClubPresident,simpleUser.

Relations are:

A Federation hasMany Associations

An Association hasMany Clubs

A Club hasMany Users

I use Laravel, so I defined policies to manages what user can and can't access.

But, then, A FederationUser may CRUD all users in his federation, while a clubPresident can just CRUD users from his club.

I end up with this kind of code:

Association.php ( Model )

```
public static function fillSelect()
{
    $associations = new Collection();
    if (Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
        $associations = Association::pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('-', 0);
    } else if (Auth::user()->isFederationPresident()) {
        $associations = Auth::user()->federationOwned->associations->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('-', 0);
    } else if (Auth::user()->isAssociationPresident()) {
        $association = Auth::user()->associationOwned;
        $associations->push($association);
        $associations = $associations->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('-', 0);
    } else if (Auth::user()->isClubPresident()) {
        $association = Auth::user()->clubOwned->association;
        $associations->push($association);
        $associations = $associations->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('-', 0);
    }
    return $associations;
}
```

Club.php

```
public static function fillSelect()
{
    $clubs = new Collection();
    if (Auth::user()->isSuperAdmin()) {
        $clubs = Club::pluck('name', 'id');
    } else if (Auth::user()->isFederationPresident() && Auth::user()->federationOwned != null) {
        $clubs = Auth::user()->federationOwned->clubs;
    } else if (Auth::user()->isAssociationPresident() && Auth::user()->associationOwned != null) {
        $clubs = Auth::user()->associationOwned->clubs->pluck('name', 'id');
    } else if (Auth::user()->isClubPresident() && Auth::user()->clubOwned != null) {
        $clubs = Auth::user()->clubOwned->pluck('name', 'id');
    }
    return $clubs;
}
```

I feel this is not so good, as for each model, I have to make numerous if().

Is there anyway to improve this kind of stuff?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust can help you.

Comment: I already use Permission with Policies, and I don't really need roles. Besides, I don't like very much to create a so big dependance to a third party plugin. I used another plugin like that (Sentinel) in the past, and when Laravel 5.2 got released, I had to wait like 2 month for them to update their component so I were able to update to L5.2...

Comment: I would argue that "superUser" or "associationPresident" is a role. If you don't want to use a 3rd party plugin you can probably treat them as roles and develop your own middleware which may act as filters to routes. Not sure if that's the best way to go about it but it moves the business logic outside the ORM.